# Asynchronous SMPP additional data

Tags: asynchronous, parameters, listener, smpp

I'm working on an SMPP client implementation in Java (JMS) using Logica's library and simulator for testing purposes.

Is there any way to embed custom data (such as a tag or an internal id) that can be sent to the provider and received back at the listener?. My attempts to use extra-optional params were unsuccessful since they do not arrive as part of the response.

So far the SMPP response PDU has a sequence number and operation status code. Is there a way to embed further information so I can use it when the listener receives the response? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I realized after some research that it not possible to embbed custom information within SMPP pdu. It is up to the SMSC to return or not any additional information other than the status and sequence number in the pdu response.